# Habilitar .NET Framework 4.5 en Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, installation, frameworks, server

install the .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows Server 2008 and is not recognized by the IIS7, because not listed in the options appears only net framework 2.0 and 4.0, anything else I need to have, and I will some day with this. thanks

Comment: Did you already try running aspnet_regiis.exe from the .NET Framework folder? Also note that 4.5 is listed as Version 4.0.30319 in IIS.

Comment: ok, then I will review and I will be sending my answer, thanks

Comment: Where is the file aspnet_regiis.exe ?, thanks

Comment: This tool is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\

Comment: ok, thanks, funciono!